# How does a Maven plugin know when to re-run?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How does a Maven plugin know when to re-run when a `clean` isn't part of execution?

That is, when I do `mvn install` as opposed to `mvn clean install`, how does it know which files have changed and which plugins it should/shouldn't run?

I ask because I seem to have a troublesome plugin that seems to be missing some changes and I don't want to "recompile the world" every single time and I also don't want to have to actively think when to do a `clean` or not.

Comment: See [The Maven Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Comment: @Kenny I understand the build lifecycle, what I'm saying is that sometimes my jar won't have my changes after I do `mvn install`, but if I do `mvn clean install` it will. So I'm asking how a plugin determines if it needs to re-run or not.

Comment: That should be explained there: all lifecycle phases up to and including the command you specify are run. Each plugin determines on it's own whether files have changed (i.e. file timestamp of .java > timestamp of .class). You might have bound the troublesome plugin to the wrong lifecycle phase. Can you add the relevant section of your POM (`<build>` for example), which plugin it is, and what files are not updated?

Comment: @Kenney It's in the correct phase, it's the cxf-codegen-plugin. The problem is that when the xsd's used by the wsdl change it doesn't detect it. I've downloaded the sourcecode for it and really my best guess by looking at it is that it doesn't realize the wsdl's depend on the xsd files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I have found there is no universal way this is done. The general idea is that timestamps of sources and targets are compared, but some plugins aren't "smart" enough to know what the sources are.

The specific problem I was running into was the cxf-codegen-plugin not considering that the `.wsdl` files may depend on `.xsd` files. So if the `.xsd` file was modified, meaning the compiled code would change if it ran again, but it did not run the plugin.